# Show if C is the boundary of the of the rectangle $x \in [0,3],\; y \in [0,2]$, then...

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's the full problem:

> If $C_0$ denotes a positively oriented circle $|z-z_0|=R$, then
>   $$\int_{C_0} (z-z_0)^{n-1}=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        0 & : n\neq 0 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
>        i2\pi & : n =0
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>   Show if C is the boundary of the of the rectangle $x \in [0,3],\; y \in [0,2]$, described in
>   the positive sense, then
>   $$\int_{C} (z-(2+i))^{n-1}=\left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        0 & : n\neq 0 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
>        i2\pi & : n =0
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$

Now, there is a Theorem and corollary that is adapted from the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem for multiply-connected regions that states

> **Theorem**
>
> Suppose that
>
> (a) $C$ is a simple closed contour, described in the counterclockwise direction;
>
> (b) $C_k$ ($k\in [1,n] \subset \mathbb{Z})$ are simple closed contours interior to $C$, all described in the clockwise direction, that are disjoint and whose interiors have no points in
>   common.
>
> If a function $f$ is analytic on all of these contours and throughout the multiply
>   connected domain consisting of the points inside $C$ and exterior to each $C_k$, then
>   $$\int_{C} f(z)dz + \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{C_k} f(z)dz=0$$

$$\\
\\
\\$$

> **Corollary**
>
> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ denote positively oriented simple closed contours,
>   where $C_1$ is interior to $C_2$. If a function $f$ is analytic in the closed region consisting of those contours and all points between them, then
>   $$\int_{C_2}f(z)dz=\int_{C_1}f(z)dz$$

So here's what I've been thinking: it's apparent here that we have $z_0=2+i$, so the disk we're dealing with has a center contained in our rectangle. Since $C$ bounds our rectangle, can we choose any arbitrary $R$ like $5$? I mean, we know that the rectangle is strictly less than $5$, so that should work, right? So ultimately we'll be dealing with the region between $C$ and our rectangle (excluding the inside of the rectangle). Assuming my deduction is correct, then we could apply the corollary stated above? I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. If anyone could lend a hand, I'd be a very thankful fella.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma_0(t) = 2+i+e^{i 2 \pi t}$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and let
$\gamma_1(t) = \begin{cases} 12t, & 0 \le t < {1 \over 4}\\
3+8i(t-{1 \over 4}), & {1 \over 4} \le t < {2 \over 4} \\
3+2i-12(t - {2 \over 4}), & {2 \over 4} \le t < {3 \over 4} \\
2i-8i(t-{3 \over 4}), & {3 \over 4} \le t \le 1
\end{cases}$.

Note that $f(z) = (z-(2+i))^{n-1}$ is analytic on $([0,3]\times [0,2]) \setminus B(2+i,1)$ so your corollary applies and $\int_{\gamma_1} f = \int_{\gamma_0} f = 2 \pi i \ 1_{\{0\}}(n)$ as desired.

Comment: Umm...super confusing. I really am not sure how to came up with your equations. Thank you for the efforts, though!

Comment: What is confusing? Just plot $\gamma_0$, it traces out the boundary of the rectangle in an anti-clockwise direction. The equations just interpolate between the points $0, 3, 3+2i, 2i$ and back to $0$ again.